# Django ORM: using combination of F, MAX and GROUP BY

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm, django-2.1

I have the custom model manager, which overrides `create` method. Target model has `order_nbr` field, which represents the order of an item. I want to increment the MAX value of `order_nbr` by one. The key here is that MAX value should be taken in conjuction with GROUP BY. Please, take a look on my code (which still could be affected by race condition):

```
class ContentOnPageModelManager(models.Manager):

    def create(self, **kwargs):
        if 'order_nbr' not in kwargs:
            try:
                order_nbr = ContentOnPage.objects.filter(page=kwargs['page']).latest('order_nbr').values('order_nbr')[0]
            except ContentOnPage.DoesNotExist:
                order_nbr = 0
            # TODO (dmitry): race condition
            kwargs['order_nbr'] = order_nbr + 1
        return super().create(**kwargs)



class ContentOnPage(models.Model):

    page = models.ForeignKey('Page', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    video = models.ForeignKey('Video', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    audio = models.ForeignKey('Audio', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    text = models.ForeignKey('Text', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    order_nbr = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

How can I replace that code with something like:

```
kwargs['order_nbr'] = F(GROUP_BY('page').MAX('order_nbr')) + 1
```

^^^ that's more like pseudocode though

Comment: I guess it's not possible, because I can't imagine such SQL query. Maybe kind of `insert...select`.

Comment: Would setting an signal and updating the value **after** the model is created work for you?

Comment: Since there's a gap between instance creation and update on that instance - there's still the chance for race condition to appear. So I'm looking for more reliable solution - select for update, pessimistic lock or something else.